# File gets overwritten on program restart Android

Tags: android, save, restart, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write out some data to a file. However, every time I restart my program, I think it is overwriting the original file (making a new one?) Here is a snippet of code where I instantiate things. Is there something I can change so that the file doesn't get overwritten everytime? something like if file.doesExist??

```
try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if(root.canWrite()){
        File highscoresFile = new File(root, "names.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(highscoresFile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        //out.newLine();
        out.append(name);
        out.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: When I try to read the items in the file, I only get the very last one that was put in :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely overwriting the file.  You can append to the end of the file with the FileWriter by using a different constructor.

Instead use

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(highscoresFile, true);
```

The boolean at the end tells you whether or not to append to the end of the file.

Comment: How can I make it write to a new line and still append? Is it just "write"??

Comment: You probably want to flip flop your out.append(name); and out.newLine(); (and of course uncomment it too!)  I believe this will give the desired effect.

Comment: okay, I did this. I think my problem now is when I start to store things into an array. They're all being stored in one slot of my array. Hmm....I might have to find another way to work around this.